# How to make text field to people picker in edit form in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

There is text filed in which "Author" name saved while submitting new form but while editing that form is there any way by which I can make it People picker and user can select the new name name and save the changes.

Comment: Please provide more information. Looka t https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Naveen's answer's will not work for you.

The Client People Picker does not apply to SharePoint 2013 on-premise, except when writing a custom AddIn which you are not doing.

You also can't change the existing Text field of Author to be a people field directly as that is an illegal/invalid field type modification.

You will need to edit your existing field and rename it to something like AuthorOld/AuthorText. And then create a new field as a person field named Author.

However, it sounds like you're trying to let the user edit the field for who created the item. That field is locked for editing by end users. You can however, hide that field and just create a new person field with a default value of [Me] (this fills in the current users name when they create an item). Which will let you get the behavior it sounds like you're after :)

Comment: Person fields do not allow default values, so [Me] is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What my understanding is in SP Default edit form you have a Text Field to Save the User Value. Now you need to make that Text field as PeoplePicker Control.

You have 2 choice to done this. 
1) Go with OOB. Make that Text field which is used to save the "Author" name as User Field. So it will be act as a PeoplePicker control in Both New/Edit Form.

2) Add Content Editor Webpart in the Edit Form. And make that Text Field as Client people picker.

Refer for 
[Client People Picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx)

Mark as answer if it helps.